# From Job Number update automatically whenever its value changed

Tags: .net, vb.net

looking to an idea to reduce repetitive code

```
Dim varJobNumber = "1234"
lblJobNumber.text = varJobNumber
```

whenever `varJobNumber` changes its value the update `lblJobNumber.text` automatically on the interface rather than repeating the same code line `lblJobNumber.text = varJobNumber` again and again. Property in public module
any better solution?

```
my approach

Public Module
```

```
Private JobNumber_ As String
Public Property JobNumber() As String
    Get
        Return JobNumber_
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
       JobNumber_= value
       frmInvoice.lblJobNumber.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

```
    form level
```

```
JobNumber="351759"     ' New invoice number
JobNumber="1224"     ' next invoice number
JobNumber="5463"     ' nextinvoice number
```

```
    form level, it keep updating
```

validation and condition may apply additional

Comment: Have a read up on Data Bindings and INotify

Comment: Not a good idea to have your a property of your Job class dependent on the existence of `frmInvoice.lblJobNumber`

Comment: it is a just example.